# writeToFile:atomically: what does atomically mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, atomic, writetofile

I am wondering what the `atomically:` parameter stands for in the `writeToFile:atomically:` method (`-[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]` for example). It is common to pass `YES` for `atomically:`, but I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

An 'atomic write' is one where you are guaranteed to have either a correct, complete write to the file or an error. There's no chance that, say, half of the write will work and then something bad happens (lost power, drive crash, etc) and the rest of the write fails. It's all or nothing. This is generally what you want.

Comment: The old file will not be changed or removed until the new version is completely on the disk.

Comment: Upvote for "This is generally what you want.", which Apple docs leaves out

Answer (score 40):

atomically

If YES, the data is written to a backup file, and then—assuming no errors occur—the backup file is renamed to the name specified by path; otherwise, the data is written directly to path.